# How to send JSON data from table through email Laravel PHP (Already sending input fields successfully)

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to grab all the data from a HTML table that is completed from a variety of Drop Down boxes. I am able to email successfully all the input fields but can not work out how to grab the JSON data.

I have converted the table data to JSON and the variable is logging fine. There is no back end database and all the data is client side and static HTML.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<h4 class="info-text"> Tell us about yourself and the project you are working on.</h4>
<div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Contact Name <small></small></label>
        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact Name..." id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Contact Number <small></small></label>
        <input name="phone" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Number..." id="number">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5 ">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="project">Please tell us a little about the project you are working on <small></small></label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="project" rows="5" id="project"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email <small></small></label>
        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="email@email.com" id="email">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Upload a file should you wish to</label>
        <input name="file" type="file" class="btn btn-info" placeholder="email@email.com">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Product</th>
            <th scope="col">Ancillary Quantity</th>
            <th scope="col">Fire Rating</th>
            <th scope="col">Void Gap (mm)</th>
            <th scope="col">Cut Type</th>
            <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
            <th scope="col">Bracket Finish</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>

        </tr>

    </tbody>

</table>
```

Here is the loop for the jQuery for the table data

```
$("#next").click(function () {

var table = $("table tbody");

table.find('tr').each(function (i) {

    var $tds = $(this).find('td')

    product = $tds.eq(1).text(),
        aNum = $tds.eq(2).text(),
        firerating = $tds.eq(3).text(),
        voidgap = $tds.eq(4).text(),
        sizetype = $tds.eq(5).text(),
        numofeither = $tds.eq(6).text(),
        brackets = $tds.eq(7).text();

    // do something with productId, product, Quantity
    var myJson = JSON.stringify('Row ' + (i + 1) + '\nProduct: ' + product +
        '\nAncillary Quantity: ' + aNum +
        '\nFire Rating: ' + firerating +
        '\nVoid Gap: ' + voidgap +
        '\nCut Type: ' + sizetype +
        '\nQuantity: ' + numofeither +
        '\nBrackets: ' + brackets);

    console.log(myJson);
});
```

});

the PHP Request

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [            
        'name' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'project' => 'required',
        'row' => 'required',       
    ];
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, I have spent a number of hours searching for help to no avail.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your controller use `json_decode()`

```
$tableData = json_decode($request->row, true); # true -- get as array
```

Then pass $tableData to your email blade and print it.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I have been struggling to find the right question to ask to solve this issue.

Comment: You are welcome :D If it is working could you mark it as helpful.